# Здравствуйте тут у меня проблема с циклом for.После запуска происходит что то такое

Tags: python, алгоритм

[введите сюда описание изображения][1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Табуляции с пробелами попутались. Внешне отступ такой же, а внутренне - другой. Лучше использовать что-то одно... P.S. Это ж надо быть извращенцем - придумать синтаксис, построенный на отступах... :(

Comment: @Harry везде свои приколы. Придумали ЯП и с синтаксисом на точках с запятыми, и со скобками .. брр-р.. маньяки )

Comment: @Kromster Со скобками - это ещё ладно. По их хоть редакторы могут попарно подсвечивать и по ним прыгать. А а Питоне: вот нужно мне временно какой if или for закомментировать, а их тело оставить - так будь добр, двигай кучу строк влево. А потом обратно.

Comment: @GrAnd обычно в IDE можно выделить блок и Tab / Shift+Tab двигать его целиком на отступ вправо/влево.

Comment: @Harry давайте не будем переходить на личности?

Answer (score 0):

Вы слишком много раз нажали на Tab. Вам нужно убрать по одной табуляции на двух строчках (20, 21), т.к. 20-ая и 21-ая строчка кода принадлежат функции parse() и им нужна только одна табуляция. Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
def parse():
    # Ваш код
    for comp in comps:
        print(comp['title'])
    # Продолжение вашего кода
```